# Rails Absolute URL for public directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, absolute

What is the method I need to call to find the root URL for a rails application. For example, I have a site where the address is "https://host:1234/foo/app-main".

What method should I be using to get "https://host:1234/foo/images" to get the absolute url for images in the public url?

Answer (score 3):

[image_path](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_path)(image_name)

Edit: Steve has a good point, this will only get you part of the way there. To get the rest you must be inside of a request (you probably are)

In that case though, you can combine the above with Justice's approach,

```
"#{request.scheme}://#{request.host_with_port}/#{request.script_name}#{image_path(image_name)}"
```

Comment: That will return a URL relative to the server's root, not an absolute URL.

Answer (score 0):

This question makes sense only on a per-request basis, since your one process might easily be listening on multiple domain names and on multiple schemes.

```
"#{request.scheme}://#{request.host_with_port}#{request.script_name}"
```

See [`Rack::Request`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb).